# Peertalk socket connection return -1 when trying to connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, sockets

I am creating an app that communicating between Mac and iPhone. I am using [Peertalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) for this purpose.

I just copied that Peertalk core files to my project and run, But the socket connection return -1

```
  // Connect socket
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(addr.sun_path, "/var/run/usbmuxd");
  socklen_t socklen = sizeof(addr);
  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, socklen) == -1) {
    if (error) *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:errno userInfo:nil];
    return NO;
  }
```

But when I run the original code that connection was successful and I got the `PTUsbHub` object and connection return `success` value.

Sample code in obj c

```
- (void)startListeningForDevices {
  NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

  [nc addObserverForName:PTUSBDeviceDidAttachNotification object:PTUSBHub.sharedHub queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
NSNumber *deviceID = [note.userInfo objectForKey:@"DeviceID"];
    //code to connect 
  }];

  [nc addObserverForName:PTUSBDeviceDidDetachNotification object:PTUSBHub.sharedHub queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSNumber *deviceID = [note.userInfo objectForKey:@"DeviceID"];
    //code to disconnect
  }];
}
```

My swift code

```
@objc private func startListening(){
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.PTUSBDeviceDidAttach, object: PTUSBHub.shared(), queue: nil) { (notification) in
        let deviceID = notification.userInfo?["DeviceID"] as? NSNumber
    }


    nc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.PTUSBDeviceDidDetach, object: PTUSBHub.shared(), queue: nil, using: { note in
        let deviceID = note.userInfo?["DeviceID"] as? NSNumber

  }
```

So the problem is I am not getting the attach or detach notification because the connection was unsuccessful.

Is there any permission needs? or can you somebody figure out what is the real problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what is the `error`? From what I understand, this Objective C code is their sample code. What's your actual Swift code?

Comment: @Alexander please look now

Comment: where do you actually make the connections?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found my mistake. It is about app sandboxing. You can read the article about the sandboxing

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox_entitlements
2. https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/

It is security feature by mac.

I just unchecked the app sandboxing and it is working.

Thankyou